# make an image 'onclickable' in a js object

Tags: javascript, image, object, onclick

The js object below will, after instantiation, produce the specified image. what I'd like is to get the image to execute `sayQuote` when clicked in the browser. Suggestions?

```
function CharType()
{
    this.charImage = function(whichImage) 
        {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = "characters/"+whichImage;
        document.body.appendChild(image);
        }
    function sayQuote()
        {
        alert(getQuote());
        }
//  this.onclick = sayQuote();  // nope, that doesn't do it!
}
```

the instantiation:

```
var stickfigure = new CharType();
stickfigure.charImage("stickfigure.png");
```

Comment: pretty much just this, really. The getQuote function delivers a quote. I added the instantiation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
function CharType()
{
    function sayQuote()
    {
            alert(getQuote());
    }

    this.charImage = function(whichImage) 
    {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = "characters/"+whichImage;
        image.onclick = sayQuote;
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

Basically, the image created in this.charImage is your image object with the onclick property, not the new object surrounding it that you created.

Comment: that makes total sense! alas, it does the same thing as the code I presented would uncommented: run sayQuote right away, and do nothing onClick.

Comment: my bad, should have been `image.onclick = sayQuote;` not `image.onclick = sayQuote();`

Comment: Yes! That also works, as does Sudhir's. Can you explain why that makes the difference? Thanks.

Comment: `image.onclick = sayQuote;` puts a reference to the function sayQuote in image.onclick, while `image.onclick = sayQuote();` executes the function sayQuote and puts what it returns in image.onclick, namely, `undefined`.

Comment: ah. so `sayQuote()` is actually calling the function (RTL parsing...), whereas `sayQuote` is merely referring to is as an object... ?

Comment: basically, yes. image.onclick = sayQuote; is assigning a reference to the function to image.onclick, not calling it and assigning the result of the call. objects are specific things in javascript, but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CharType()
{
    function sayQuote()
    {
        alert(getQuote());
    }

    this.charImage = function(whichImage) 
    {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = "characters/"+whichImage;

        image.addEventListener("click", this.sayQuote, false);

        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }
}
```